# |Rust| What's the most performant way of initializing a BIG and RANDOMIZED array?

Tags: arrays, random, rust

*Note i'm using the 'rand' crate.

I'm new to rust and through some research and testing I was able to find two solutions to this:

#1: This on initializes an array and then populates it with random values:

```
type RandomArray = [usize; 900]; 

pub fn make_array() -> RandomArray {

    let mut rng = thread_rng();
    
    let mut arr: RandomArray = [0; 900];
        
    for i in 0..900 {
        //I need a range of random values!
        arr[i] = rng.gen_range(0..900)
    }

    arr
}
```

#2: This one initializes an array, it populates it with values from 0 to 900 and then shuffles it:

```
type RandomArray = [usize; 900]; 

pub fn make_shuffled_array() -> RandomArray  {
    let mut rng = thread_rng();
    
    let mut arr: RandomArray = [0; 900];
        
    for i in 0..900 {
        arr[i] = i;
    }

    arr.shuffle(&mut rng);

    arr
}
```

Through my testing, it seems like '#1' is slower but more consistent. But **none of these actually initializes the array with the random range of numbers.**

Both of these seem to be pretty fast and simple, however, I'm sure that there is an even faster way of doing this.

Comment: BIG is relative. A heap-allocated array of hundreds of megabytes could be zero-allocated (which is ~free) and then initialized in chunks from a threadpool if your program already has one lying around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to generating "random" data I don't know what exactly you need. To me #1 seems like it does what you describe. If you want to have random range bounds you can generate them first and only then use `gen_range`.

When it comes to the performance #1 should be *faster*, since it walks the whole array twice (once in the creation, and once in the initialization), but #2 walks it three times (creation, initialization and shuffling). You can't really do anything about the initialization part, but you *can* skip the "creation" part.

Rust requires that *all* data is initialized. Therefore you must specify what elements are in your array at the beginning, event though you will overwrite it on the next step. To opt-out from this you can use rust's special type [`MaybeUninit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html). I encourage you to read carefully it's documentation, since using it is *very* `unsafe`, but here you have a simple example of how you could use it.

```rust
use std::mem::{transmute, MaybeUninit};

fn get_random() -> usize {
    // chosen by fair dice roll.
    // https://xkcd.com/221/
    4
}

const N: usize = 900;

fn make_array() -> [usize; N] {
    // Unstable MaybeUninit::uninit_array
    let mut array: [MaybeUninit<usize>; N] =
        unsafe { MaybeUninit::<[MaybeUninit<usize>; N]>::uninit().assume_init() };

    for x in &mut array {
        x.write(get_random());
    }

    // Acts like unstable MaybeUninit::array_assume_init
    let array: [usize; N] = unsafe { transmute(array) };

    array
}
```

Comment: [array::from_fn](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/array/fn.from_fn.html) uses an uninitialized array under the hood so it may provide the same performance with more concise code.